# Can anyone help me how to call this function parameter from class to be displayed in my output

Tags: c++, overloading, function-calls

This coding where I used function overloading is a code where user have to input their pointer for 4 subjects and its credit hour so it prints out their GPA. The thing is I have 3 parameter in Student(string test123, string nama, string vinto ). But I only want to display either one of the string. Lets say I want the Vinto to be print out. How can I call the vinto in my Display function so that it prints out Vinto. Heres's My coding.

CPP.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
    string nama;
    string test123;
    int i;

    Student StudentA(test123, nama, "vinto");

    cout << "key in points for 4 subject\n";
    StudentA.Getpointers();

    StudentA.Display(test123);

}
```

Student.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(string test123, string nama, string vinto );
    void Getpointers();
    void Display(string name);

private:
    double points[4];
    int creditHours[4];
    string name;
    double CalculateGPA();
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

Student::Student(string test123, string nama, string vinto)
{
    name = nama;
}
void Student::Getpointers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "points for subject :" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> points[i];
        cout << "credit hour for subject " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> creditHours[i];
    }
}
void Student::Display(string name)
{
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    cout << "Your current GPA is " << setprecision(3) << CalculateGPA() << endl;
}
double Student::CalculateGPA()
{
    double totalpoints = 0;
    int totalcreditHours = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        totalpoints += (points[i] * creditHours[i]);
        totalcreditHours += creditHours[i];
    }

    return totalpoints / totalcreditHours;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `vinto` argument of your constructor is not saved anywhere, so in this example you cannot get it back. However, you could store it:

First, add a `vinto` field to the class:

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student(string test123, string nama, string vinto );
    void Getpointers();
    void Display(string name);

private:
    double points[4];
    int creditHours[4];
    string name;
    string vinto;
    double CalculateGPA();
};
```

Then, store the `vinto` argument value in this field:

```
Student::Student(string test123, string nama, string vinto)
{
    name = nama;
    this->vinto = vinto;
}
```

After this, you may use vinto:

```
void Student::Display(string name)
{
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    cout << "Your current GPA is " << setprecision(3) << CalculateGPA() << endl;
    cout << "Your vinto is " << vinto << endl;
}
```

Also, it's a bit strange that you store student's `name` in the object field, but use another name (which is passed to `Student::Display`) to say Hello to him.

Comment: Is there any way where i can just call either one of the 3 parameters((string test123, string nama, string vinto)) into Display() so at the end it prints out the parameter that i call in Display(). Lets say if i want vinto to be displayed at the end i put display(vinto) and i want to assign it to the value name.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. The code in the method (like, inside `Student::Display`) has access only to some data (global variables, method arguments and class members, for example), so you should put your data somewhere in this memory. The code example above puts `vinto` in the class member. Maybe passing it as a method argument is preferrable here.